# Using two variables set as DOM elements to create a new variable targeting both DOM elements

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, radio-button, jquery-selectors

Another simple question which I think to be impossible, I am very hopeful you will once again prove me wrong!

Start off with two variables, pointing at DOM elements:

```
myFirstVariable = $('.my-little-radio input[type=radio]');
mySecondVariable = $('.my-little-select select');
```

We then need to run a check on any actions made on both of these variables, but only once and in the same function. The question is how do we ping both of the variables into a query selector all style variable to check against?

```
var myMultiVariable = $(myFirstVariable, mySecondVariable);
myMultiVariable.on('change', function() {
    // I am not crazy!
});
```

As far as I can tell, the above will only work for the myFirstVariable, and not for the other selectors chained.

**Specific question: How can I chain two variables set as DOM elements together to attach an event listener in order to only run the function once?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain why your attempt didn't work; it's because the `$(a, b)` syntax is used to find the `a` selector within `b`. It's analogous to `$(b).find(a)`;

There's a couple of ways to do what you require.

One would be to use the [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add) method:

```
var myMultiVariable = myFirstVariable.add(mySecondVariable);
```

Alternatively put both the elements in an array and supply that to the jQuery object:

```
var myMultiVariable = $([myFirstVariable, mySecondVariable]);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right, my bad. That'll teach me to not read my own links :) I assumed jQuery just appended the second objects contents to the first instead of creating extra overhead of creating an entirely new object. Either way, I removed that note.

Comment: I was *sure* it was me misunderstanding something. :-) That's how good your answers are, in my experience.

Comment: Thank you, my friend, that's very kind of you to say.